# How to set the size of an NSToolbarItem on macOS Ventura since setMaxSize is deprecated?

Tags: macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

Everything works as expected when using `[toolbarItem setMaxSize: NSMakeSize(24,24)]`- but this function is deprecated now.

I tried to set the layout constraints on the items's view but that does not have any effect.

```
        NSView *itemView = toolbarItem.view;
        itemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [itemView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: 24];
        NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [itemView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant: 24];

        widthConstraint.active = YES;
        heightConstraint.active = YES;
```

Comment: Is the view a custom view?

Comment: No - we want to use the standard items with icon + text.

Comment: The documentation of `maxSize` links to [Setting a Toolbar Item’s Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Toolbars/Tasks/SettingTBItemSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000754): "The minSize and maxSize toolbar item properties are for use only by view items.".

Comment: I know that. But as the title already said: setMaxSize is deprecated. I need a solution without it.